# How to update shipping methods on change of custom dropdown on cart page

Tags: magento2, cart, uicomponent, knockoutjs

I have created a custom dropdown above country dropdown on cart page. Now I want to update shipping methods list.

I followed [Devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html) to show custom field on address form (cart page). All in all I want to bind custom dropdown (dropdown have options as all shipping addresses of customer) so that it works same as country, region and postcode and update shipping method list as per selected address from dropdown.

Thanks